# 3D графика без glm

Tags: c++, opengl

Я учил OpenGL без использования glm. Сейчас у меня есть обычная 3D сцена, которая нормально работает со стандартными шейдерами. Но когда я попытался написать их самостоятельно - ничего не получилось. Как я понял, для написания шейдеров для 3D сцен требуется glm (возможно я ошыбаюсь). Есть ли возможность как то обойтись без этого? Все свои матричные махинации со сценой я делал с помощью glRotatef glTranslatef и так далее. Есть ли возможность хотя бы просто вывести в окно мою 3D сцену с не стандартными шейдерами? Есть ли у кого то код таких шейдеров?

Comment: Да, можно. Glm - это просто удобная оболочка.

Comment: Стандартных шейдеров никаких нет, однако 2д контент можно без выводить без матричных манипуляций. А как раз для написания шейдеров glm не используется, так как они пишутся на языке GLSL.